# DRF Serializers The problem with def create()

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework

The problem is that I want to create two model objects with one query. My models:

```py
class Auction(models.Model):

    title=models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Auction'
        verbose_name_plural='Auctions'


class AuctionImage(models.Model):
    # FK TO AUCTION
    auction=models.ForeignKey(
        Auction,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='images'
    )
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='auction_images/'
    )
```

My BaseSerializers

```py
class BaseAuctionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
      model = Auction
      fields = (
         'title',
      )

class BaseAuctionImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   auction = BaseAuctionSerializer()
   image = serializers.ImageField()

   class Meta:
      model = AuctionImage
      fields = (
         'auction',
         'image',
      )
```

My main Serializer is

```py
class CreateAuctionSerializer(BaseAuctionImageSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        pass
```

But when i try to send POST request content-type form-data in Swagger i get an error
[image: request payload]
[image: response]
When I create separate models, everything works, when together it does not. Tried another option when I explicitly prescribe fields in serializer

```py
image = serializers.ImageField()
```

It works too.
But I don't like this variant, I want to build everything inherited. What's the reason for my mistake?

P.S my view

```py
class AuctionView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                mixins.DestroyModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                mixins.ListModelMixin,viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    default_queryset = Auction.objects.all()
    default_serializer_class = RetrieverAuctionSerializer

    multi_serializer_classes = {
        'create': CreateAuctionSerializer,
        'retrieve': RetrieverAuctionSerializer,
        'partial_update': UpdateAuctionSerializer,
        'list': ListAuctionSerializer,
    }

    multi_queryset = {
        'create': AuctionImage.objects.all(),
        'retrieve': Auction.objects.all(),
        'partial_update': Auction.objects.all(),
        'destroy': Auction.objects.all(),
        'list': AuctionImage.objects.all(),
    }

    http_method_names = ('get', 'post', 'patch', 'delete')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.multi_queryset.get(self.action, self.default_queryset)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.multi_serializer_classes.get(self.action, self.default_serializer_class)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = super().create(request, *args, **kwargs).data
        return AuctionResponses.create_auction_success(data)
```

I expect to send this format

```py
auction: {
  "title": "string"
}
image: (binary)
```

And get in validated_data auction and image

Answer (score 0):

you cannot send nested data in multipart/form_data. You have to handle saving image files separately and only work only with JSON data in REST API's   or you can use this package [drf-nested-froms](https://pypi.org/project/drf-nested-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

```py
def __request_data_to_json(self, data):
        '''
        The method allows you to work with form-data, intercept data
        convert it to what this bad endpoint needs (in JSON)
        '''
        if type(data) == QueryDict:
            data = data.dict()
        
        for key, value in self.get_serializer().get_fields().items():
            if isinstance(value, serializers.ListSerializer) or \
            isinstance(value, serializers.ModelSerializer):
                if key in data and type(data[key]) == str:
                    try:
                        data[key] = None if \
                        data[key] == '' else \
                        json.loads(data[key]) 
                    except:
                        raise serializers.ValidationError(AuctionResponses.invalid_json_data())
        return data

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = self.__request_data_to_json(request.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        return AuctionResponses.create_auction_success(serializer.data)
```